# Is there a personal tax liability on corporate ESA contributions?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, coverdell-esa

According to the IRS publication on Coverdell ESA, https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc310:

> You may be able to contribute to a Coverdell ESA to finance the beneficiary's qualified education expenses. Contributions must be made in cash, and they're not deductible. Any individual whose modified adjusted gross income is under the limit set for a given tax year can make contributions. **Organizations, such as corporations and trusts can also contribute regardless of their adjusted gross income**. Contributors must contribute by the due date of their tax return (not including extensions). There's no limit to the number of accounts that can be established for a particular beneficiary; however, the total contribution to all accounts on behalf of a beneficiary in any year can't exceed $2,000.

As the contributions are after-tax, for the corporation that money would not be deductible.

Does the owner of the ESA (either the parent or the child) have any tax liability associated with the contribution?

If not, does this mean that if you own a business you can add $2,000 per year, per child, to an ESA and pay only the corporate tax rates rather than personal tax rates on the money?